# Jquery custom validator not working for Australian business number - ABN with mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have been working on this for some time now and ended up resorting to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/si2030/s6w94nxs/) which is returning errors that I cant fix. Its giving this error:

> {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name':

Apart from the jsFiddle problem the problem with the validator is the method was set to run through a pure number with no dashes.

So I added a new variable which stripped out the dashes

```
var testValue = parseInt(value.replace(/-/g, ""));
```

but it giving an error or NaN - Not a number on the final Tally variable.

What I wanted to do is apply a genuine ABN number in mask format eg 81-050-237-986 and process it with the method and get true.

Here is the validator function:

```
      jQuery.validator.addMethod('abnValidate', function abnValidate(value, element) {
        if (value.length == 14) {
            var testValue = parseInt(value.replace(/-/g, ""));
            var weighting = [10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19];
            var tally = (parseInt(testValue[0]) - 1) * weighting[0];
            for (var i = 1; i < testValue.length; i++) {
                tally += (parseInt(value[i]) * weighting[i]);
            }
            return (tally % 89) == 0;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });

    $("#ABN").rules("add", {
        abnValidate: true,
        messages: {
            abnValidate: "The ABN does not conform to the ATO's algorithm"
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**
You can look at the formula the ATO uses is [here](http://downloads.icbglobal.org/au/ATO/ATO_Format_of_the_ABN_NAT2956.pdf).

Basically the process is as follows:

```
To verify an ABN:
To verify an ABN:
1. Subtract 1 from the first (left) digit to give a new eleven digit number
2. Multiply each of the digits in this new number by its weighting factor
3. Sum the resulting 11 products
4. Divide the total by 89, noting the remainder
5. If the remainder is
zero
the number is valid
```

Comment: What is `testValue[0]` supposed to evaluate to? By that point it will be a number.

Comment: I have added an edit to the question that answers this in (1) above.

Comment: As I said above, `testValue` is a number, you can't index into it like that. You want something more like: `var testValue = value.replace(/-/g, '').split('').map(function(n) { return parseInt(n, 10); });`

Comment: Added that to the function. Firefox hangs when I try and step through the method however if I place the breakpoint at the return Tally has a value of NaN. Not sure why Firefox is hanging on this method either.

Comment: Found the problem apart from not representing testValue correctly I was parsing value and not testvalue in the loop. I have upvoted Evans answer as its provided the number I needed.

Answer (score 1):

My ABN number Validation with ABN number format masking

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#contact_abn_no").mask("00 000 000 000", {
    onChange: function() {
      console.log($('#contact_abn_no').val());
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#register_form").validate({
    rules: {
      "abn_no": {
        checkAbn: true,
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "abn_no": {
        required: "Please Enter ABN Number"
      }
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $("#loading").css("visibility", "hidden");
      return false;
      $("#loading").css("visibility", "visible");
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });

  $.validator.addMethod("checkAbn", function(value, element) {
    var abn_val = $("#contact_abn_no").val()
    if (abn_val.trim() != '') {
      var weights = [10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19];
      if (abn_val.length == 14) {
        //remove spaces from string
        abn_val = abn_val.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        // strip anything other than digits
        abn_val = abn_val.replace("/[^\d]/", "");
        // check length is 11 digits
        if (abn_val.length == 11) {
          // apply ato check method 
          var sum = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            var digit = abn_val[i] - (i ? 0 : 1);
            var sum = sum + (weights[i] * digit);
          }
          return ((sum % 89) == 0);
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    // return true;
  }, "ABN number not vailid.");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>
      <form id="register_form" class="forms-sample" method="post" action="register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>ABN Number</label>
          <input id="contact_abn_no" type="text" name="abn_no" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="ABN Number">
          <span class="text-danger" style="font-size:12px;display:none;">{{ $errors->first('abn_no') }}</span>

        </div>
        <br/>
        <div>
          <button style="margin-top:0px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-block_top_margin btnsubload">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My JavaScript version of validating ABN and ACN

ABN:

```
function isValidABN(num) {
    const weights = new Array(10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19);
    // Convert to string and remove all white space
    num = num.toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
    // Split it to number array
    num = num.split('').map(n => parseInt(n));
    // Subtract 1 from the first (left-most) digit of the ABN to give a new 11 digit number
    num[0] = num[0] - 1;
    // Multiply each of the digits in this new number by a "weighting factor" based on its position as shown in the table below
    num = num.map((n, i) => n * weights[i]);
    // Sum the resulting 11 products
    let total = num.reduce((acc, n) => {
        return acc + n;
    }, 0);
    // Divide the sum total by 89, noting the remainder
    if(total % 89 === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

ACN:

```
function isValidACN(num) {
    const weights = new Array(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    // Convert to string and remove all white space
    num = num.toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
    // Split it to number array
    num = num.split('').map(n => parseInt(n));
    // Set the check digit and remove it 
    let checkDigit = num.pop();
    // Apply weighting to digits 1 to 8.
    num = num.map((n, i) => n * weights[i]);
    // Sum the products
    let total = num.reduce((acc, n) => {
        return acc + n;
    }, 0);
    // Divide by 10 to obtain remainder
    let calculatedCheckDigit = (10 - (total % 10)) % 10;
    // calculatedCheckDigit should match check digit
    if(calculatedCheckDigit === checkDigit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```